# Interaction between invalidateLater and DT click events

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt

In my shiny app, I have a `textInput` field that can either be filled out manually or by clicking on a cell in a `datatable` from the `DT` library. I would like to display that table live, using `invalidateLater`. However, when the `textInput` is filled by clicking on a cell, it is cleared when the table refreshes. How can I prevent that?

MRE (the `get_table` and `modify_input` parts are more complex in the actual app):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

### formatting function
get_table <- function(){
  my_table <- data.frame(Animal = c("Monkey","Giraffe","Rhino","Hippo"),Plant = c("Apple Tree","Birch","Cypress","Oak"),
                         Food = c("Burger","Ice Cream","Pasta","Pizza"))
  my_table <- datatable(my_table)
  return(my_table)
}

### transform cell entries to usable inputs
modify_input <- function(value){
  return(tolower(value))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("my_input",label = "Enter an animal, plant or dish!"),
  dataTableOutput("my_table")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  my_table <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(5000,session)
    get_table()
  })
  
  cell_input <- reactive({
    modify_input(input$my_table_cell_clicked$value)
  })
  
  observe({
    cell_input()
    updateTextInput(session,"my_input",label = "Enter an animal, plant or dish!",value = cell_input())
  })
  
  output$my_table <- renderDT({
    my_table()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `input$my_table_cell_clicked` is an empty list when the table refreshes, and then `input$my_table_cell_clicked$value` is `NULL`.

Here is a solution:

```r
  cell_input <- reactive({
    value <- input$my_table_cell_clicked$value
    if(!is.null(value)) modify_input(value)
  })
```